# How to fill multidimensional array with loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array :

```php
$days = array(
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
);
```

And I have a query witch is getting me the days from the database (day_name,ID);
For what I need your help: I want to  fill the array with the loop below and make it associative. Example result :

```php
thursday => array(
    'ID' => 1,
    'name' => thursday
),
friday => array(
    'ID' => 1,
    'name' => thursday
),
....eg
```

My code now:

```php
$query='Query days from database';

foreach($query as $res)
{
    foreach($days as $day)
    {
        if($res == $day)
        {
            // now there I want to put informations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Great to have you here. Please always format your code properly, so anybody can easily read it. Also consider using the search provided on the main page of SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't initialize arrays (Like suggested in @Barmar Answer), you need to look for the array key to override it with an array. Like here :

```
$days=array('Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
       );
    print_r($days);

//Example
$res[0]['name']="Sunday";
$res[0]['ID']="7";
$res[1]['name']="Monday";
$res[1]['ID']="1";

foreach($res as $k => $v){
$daykey = array_search($res[$k]['name'], $days);
if ($daykey !== false) {
    $days[$daykey]=array($res[$k]['name']=>array('ID'=>$res[$k]['ID'],'name'=>$res[$k]['name']));
} else {
    //do nothing... or whatever
}
} 
print_r($days);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for nested loops. Initialize the array as an associative array. Then use the `name` column from the database query to index into the result and assign to that element.

```
$days = ['sunday' => [], 'monday' => [], ...];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $days[$row['name']] = $row;
}
```